# Is there a way to search for a specific column of a database table inside JetBrains IDEs (IntelliJ/RubyMine)?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, rubymine, datagrip

JetBrains' IDE has a database client where you can view the different tables rows/columns.

I have a table with hundreds of columns. Is there a way to jump/search for a specific column? Otherwise, it's very annoying to scroll through all the columns and search manually.

I'm using IntelliJ, RubyMine database clients but I assume it would be the same shortcut/way to all IDEs of JetBrains.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. Open a column list (Ctrl/Cmd+F12) and start typing.

Video example: https://youtu.be/U5SOD-eeK50?t=1221